# How can I fix a broken launcher text(label) in Ubuntu 14.04(64bit)

Tags: launcher

[image: Broken text(label) in launcher...]

[image]

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) in my pc successfully. But some launcher's text (label) is broken.

How can I fix this problem?

- I've successfully installed language packs for English (en), Korean (kr)
- I'm already setting of `LANG` in `/etc/default/locale`, `/etc/enviroment`, `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Maybe you need better fonts. Try `sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-cjk`.